# Can I create a branch in Perforce based on a historic point in time?

Tags: branch, perforce

I would like to create a branch in Perforce that is based off of some point in the past, i.e. not the current state of the current branch, is this possible?  If so, how?

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do.  The current branch is in blue, and the new desired branch is shown in green.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do it:

```
p4 copy //depot/project/dev/...@release_x_label //depot/project/release_x/...
```

The command tells Perforce to copy **//depot/project/dev/...** as of **release_x_label** to **//depot/project/release_x/...** You can run this command entirely server side using **p4 copy -v**. If you don't need a copy of the files locally it's much quicker.

You can do it in one go without needing a submit by using **p4 populate**

```
p4 populate //depot/project/dev/...@release_x_label //depot/project/release_x/...
```

I usually use copy though to make sure I don't have any typos. =)

You can do all of this with streams as well. It's a bit odd in that the revision specifier that you use to choose what to branch from gets put on the target path you're branching to.

```
p4 populate -rs //stream/dev2 //stream/dev2/...@1
```

This will populate dev2 from its parent as of changelist1.

Comment: Perfect!  Out of curiosity, is there a way to accomplish this using p4v?

Comment: To answer my own question, yes it is possible in p4v.  I ended up using the "branch" menu and it had an easy way to search for and select the label I wanted to branch from, the end result of p4v was the same "p4 copy -v" command as you suggested above, just constructed via GUI options instead.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Maybe it would need a separate question but can you populate a new 'stream' with the latter command ?

Comment: Indeed. I've added a stream example in the answer above.

Comment: From another answer and from some very basic tests, I don't think the stream version need to give the source since this has to be the parent stream anyway. I have used 'p4 populate -rS //stream/dev2 @XX' and it worked fine, taking XX changelist from parent

Comment: Maybe P4 changed their CLI API since this post was made, or maybe there was a typo.  The correct version of the third command is `p4 populate -rS //stream/dev2 //stream/dev2/...@1` (capital `S` instead of lowercase `s`).